# Why am I getting an error when combining IF, ISBLANK and VLOOKUP?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I am getting the error of "too many arguments" but unable to understand how to resolve vlookup into it.

`=IF(ISBLANK((VLOOKUP([@DESCRIPTION],Table1[#All],2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP([@DESCRIPTION],Table1[#All],2,FALSE)))`

Briefly, to return the value using vlookup from a different sheet and in case there is no value then leave the cell blank

Comment: I'm not sure, but in your formula, it doesn't say what to do if it is blank or if it isn't blank. Maybe that's causing your problem

Comment: Not sure exactly... for example:  =VLOOKUP([@DESCRIPTION],Table1[#All],2,FALSE)   gives the correct result.... and   =IF(ISBLANK(Table1[@1]),"",Table1[@1])  gives me the correct result and returns blank if no value is fund in the cell

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Misread your formula. Did you try to evaluate the formula to see in what step the problem occurs?

Comment: Thanks Michthan... extra bracket error. Though I initially assumed it but was not able to figure it out. Resolved by Yass (don't know his/her actual name)

Answer (score 1):

You wrote more ")" than needed (too many arguments mean some ")" not in its place) I removed the extra "(" and ")" Try the formula below:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(VLOOKUP([@DESCRIPTION],Table1[#All],2,FALSE)),"",VLOOKUP([@DESCRIPTION],Table1[#All],2,FALSE))
```

Comment: @Mahesh Please accept the solution. Check the faint check mark to turn it green to accept the solution. This way the rest of us doesn't investigate already solved problems. And welcome to SuperUser!